# I need to implement call kit in flutter app. which rings in every state of flutter app

Tags: flutter, callkit

Whenever a call-type notification comes device should ring like an incoming call, and It is working when the app is in the foreground state. but not working while the app is in the background, killed state.

I am using "flutter_callkit_incoming" but It works only when the app is in the foreground state.
I am facing this issue in an IOS device.

Here is the AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps
import PushKit
import flutter_callkit_incoming

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyC9A8pXDMI_uJ450kTtBrZEca90McarPPg")
      //Setup VOIP
             let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
             let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
             voipRegistry.delegate = self
             voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    // Call back from Recent history
        override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                                  continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                                  restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
            
            guard let handleObj = userActivity.handle else {
                return false
            }
            
            guard let isVideo = userActivity.isVideo else {
                return false
            }
            let nameCaller = handleObj.getDecryptHandle()[""] as? String ?? ""
            let handle = handleObj.getDecryptHandle()["handle"] as? String ?? ""
            let data = flutter_callkit_incoming.Data(id: UUID().uuidString, nameCaller: nameCaller, handle: handle, type: isVideo ? 1 : 0)
            //set more data...
            data.nameCaller = "Johnny"
            SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.startCall(data, fromPushKit: true)
            
            return super.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
        }
    
    // Handle updated push credentials
        func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
            print(credentials.token)
            let deviceToken = credentials.token.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
            print(deviceToken)
            //Save deviceToken to your server
            SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.setDevicePushTokenVoIP(deviceToken)
        }
        
        func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {
            print("didInvalidatePushTokenFor")
            SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.setDevicePushTokenVoIP("")
        }
    
    // Handle incoming pushes
        func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
            print("didReceiveIncomingPushWith")
            guard type == .voIP else { return }
            
            let id = payload.dictionaryPayload["id"] as? String ?? ""
            let nameCaller = payload.dictionaryPayload["user_name"] as? String ?? ""
            let token = payload.dictionaryPayload["token"] as? String ?? ""
            let channelName = payload.dictionaryPayload["channel_name"] as? String ?? ""
            let handle = payload.dictionaryPayload["handle"] as? String ?? ""
            let isVideo = payload.dictionaryPayload["isVideo"] as? Bool ?? false
            
            let data = flutter_callkit_incoming.Data(id: id, nameCaller: nameCaller, handle: handle, type: isVideo ? 1 : 0)
            //set more data
            data.extra = ["name": nameCaller, "token": token, "channelName" :channelName]
            //data.iconName = ...
            //data.....
            SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.showCallkitIncoming(data, fromPushKit: true)
        }
}
```

Here is main.dart

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  showCallkitIncoming(Uuid().v4());
}

Future<void> showCallkitIncoming(String uuid) async {
  var params = <String, dynamic>{
    'id': uuid,
    'nameCaller': 'Hien Nguyen',
    'appName': 'Callkit',
    'avatar': 'https://i.pravatar.cc/100',
    'handle': '0123456789',
    'type': 0,
    'duration': 30000,
    'textAccept': 'Accept',
    'textDecline': 'Decline',
    'textMissedCall': 'Missed call',
    'textCallback': 'Call back',
    'extra': <String, dynamic>{'userId': '1a2b3c4d'},
    'headers': <String, dynamic>{'apiKey': 'Abc@123!', 'platform': 'flutter'},
    'android': <String, dynamic>{
      'isCustomNotification': true,
      'isShowLogo': false,
      'isShowCallback': false,
      'ringtonePath': 'system_ringtone_default',
      'backgroundColor': '#0955fa',
      'backgroundUrl': 'https://i.pravatar.cc/500',
      'actionColor': '#4CAF50'
    },
    'ios': <String, dynamic>{
      'iconName': 'CallKitLogo',
      'handleType': '',
      'supportsVideo': true,
      'maximumCallGroups': 2,
      'maximumCallsPerCallGroup': 1,
      'audioSessionMode': 'default',
      'audioSessionActive': true,
      'audioSessionPreferredSampleRate': 44100.0,
      'audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration': 0.005,
      'supportsDTMF': true,
      'supportsHolding': true,
      'supportsGrouping': false,
      'supportsUngrouping': false,
      'ringtonePath': 'system_ringtone_default'
    }
  };
  await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  var _uuid;
  var _currentUuid;

  late final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _uuid = Uuid();
    initFirebase();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
    //Check call when open app from terminated
    checkAndNavigationCallingPage();
  }

  getCurrentCall() async {
    //check current call from pushkit if possible
    var calls = await FlutterCallkitIncoming.activeCalls();
    if (calls is List) {
      if (calls.isNotEmpty) {
        print('DATA: $calls');
        this._currentUuid = calls[0]['id'];
        return calls[0];
      } else {
        this._currentUuid = "";
        return null;
      }
    }
  }

  checkAndNavigationCallingPage() async {
    var currentCall = await getCurrentCall();
    if (currentCall != null) {
      NavigationService.instance
          .pushNamedIfNotCurrent(AppRoute.callingPage, args: currentCall);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      //Check call when open app from background
      checkAndNavigationCallingPage();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  initFirebase() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print(
          'Message title: ${message.notification?.title}, body: ${message.notification?.body}, data: ${message.data}');
      this._currentUuid = _uuid.v4();
      showCallkitIncoming(this._currentUuid);
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('Device Token FCM: $token');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      onGenerateRoute: AppRoute.generateRoute,
      initialRoute: AppRoute.homePage,
      navigatorKey: NavigationService.instance.navigationKey,
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[
        NavigationService.instance.routeObserver
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> getDevicePushTokenVoIP() async {
    var devicePushTokenVoIP =
        await FlutterCallkitIncoming.getDevicePushTokenVoIP();
    print(devicePushTokenVoIP);
  }
}
```

I am using flutter_callkit_incoming: ^1.0.2+2

Answer (score -2):

It is happening because your app is not active when it is in the background state and it is not listening for your call-type notification. Your app should also be active in the background.

For the app to remain active in the background, you can use this flutter package

[Flutter_background](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background)

Comment: My question is for IOS device and Flutter_background is not working in IOS

Comment: have you used the flutter background package for ios 

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service